# Why is my report not showing the fields I place down?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I am currently using iReport to edit and customize another report that has been previously built by someone else. The only thing I am trying to do is add a Static Text Label and a Text Field.

The text label should say "Email"
The text field should hold the variable "SHIPTOEMAIL"

The goal is to have the report include the email variable and display it when compiled.

Now, the report currently already has a Static Text Label named "Notes" and a Text Field that holds the variable "MEMO". These currently work just fine. **My problem** is that when ever I add a text label and text field (the email one) when ever I compile and run my report (without errors) the fields do not show up- though they're placed on the report.

---

My only guess, because I am very new to SQL, is that this persons SQL is what is making his fields work. Here is the code of the current SQL for the report. I have not altered a thing but maybe i need to in order for my fields to work?

```
SELECT so.id AS soid, ship.id AS shipid, so.locationgroupid AS locationgroupid, ship.statusid AS shipstatus,
ship.note AS memo, so.customerpo AS socustomerpo, ship.dateshipped AS shipdate,
COALESCE(so.shiptoname,'') AS shiptoname, so.shiptoaddress AS shiptoaddress, so.shiptocity AS shiptocity,
shipState.code AS shiptostate, so.shiptozip AS shiptozip, so.customercontact AS shiptocontact,
COALESCE(so.billtoname,'') AS billtoname, so.billtoaddress AS billtoaddress, so.billtocity AS billtocity,
billState.code AS billtostate, so.billtozip AS billtozip, COALESCE(ship.cartoncount,0) AS cartoncount,
so.datefirstship AS regshipdate, fobpoint.name AS fobpoint, shipterms.name AS ShippingTerms, ship.num AS shipnum,
carrier.name AS carriername, so.num AS sonum, shipcountry.name AS shipcountry, billcountry.name AS billcountry,
(SELECT s1.sysvalue
    FROM sysproperties s1
    WHERE s1.syskey = 'Barcodes have DI'
) AS barcodeshavedi,
company.name AS company,
contact.datus as customerphone,
paymentterms.name as paymentterms,
memo.memo as memo1,shiptophone.datus as shiptophone, shiptoemail.datus as      shiptoemail, customer.number as accountNum, billtoemail.datus as billtoemail,     upsservices.description AS shipservice


FROM ship
    INNER JOIN carrier ON ship.carrierid = carrier.id
    INNER JOIN so ON ship.soid = so.id
inner join customer on so.customerid = customer.id
INNER JOIN fobpoint ON so.fobpointid = fobpoint.id
INNER JOIN shipterms ON so.shiptermsid = shipterms.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN stateconst shipState ON so.shiptostateid = shipState.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN stateconst billState ON so.billtostateid = billState.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN countryconst shipCountry ON so.shiptocountryid = shipCountry.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN countryconst billCountry ON so.billtocountryid = billCountry.id
JOIN company ON company.id = 1
left join address on address.accountid = customer.accountid and address.typeid = 50 and address.defaultflag = 1
left join contact on contact.addressid = address.id and contact.typeid = 50 and contact.defaultflag = 1
left join paymentterms on paymentterms.id = so.paymenttermsid
left join memo on company.id = memo.recordid and memo.tableid = -776196226
left join address shippingaddress on shippingaddress.accountid = customer.accountid and shippingaddress.typeid = 10 and shippingaddress.defaultflag = 1
left join contact shiptoemail on shippingaddress.id = shiptoemail.addressid  and customer.accountid = shiptoemail.accountid and shiptoemail.typeid = 60 and shiptoemail.defaultflag = 1
left join contact shiptoPhone on shippingaddress.id = shiptoPhone.addressid  and customer.accountid = shiptoPhone.accountid and shiptoPhone.typeid = 50 and shiptoPhone.defaultflag = 1
left join contact billtoemail on billtoemail.addressid = address.id and billtoemail.accountid = customer.accountid and billtoemail.typeid = 60 and billtoemail.defaultflag = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN upsservices ON so.upsserviceid = upsservices.id
WHERE ship.id = '7'AND ship.ordertypeid = 20
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query returns data for "**shiptoemail**" ?

Answer (score 0):

First execute this query in any other console and see if it return all the values you want in the report.

If not, correct the query

If yes, use a blank normal report with all the fields that the query returns and see if it is your report design problem.